# OpenLayers plugin problem

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am working with the OpenLayers plugin. I need to project the satellite data with respect to vector data shapefile I have.  For that Andre Joost suggested to create vector grid with vector data reference system. The new problem is when I change the coordinate system to degree minutes seconds the coordinate system does not changes and it shows only the coordinates in meters itself.

What is the mistake I have made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the openlayers plugin is active, the **project** CRS must remain in EPSG:3857. That is because the openlayers plugin receives 256x256 tiles, which can not be reprojected on the fly as you can do with vector layers or Geotiffs.

Comment: I am not satisfied with the answer you suggested .see if i set the coordinates to degree,minutes and seconds i am getting as 275220°46'1"E,2133436°0'34"N but i need the answer as 72o51'31.57"E and 19o16'52.56"N .